# Need help fixing AngularJS performance issue with many elements

Tags: angularjs

Im currently facing a problem with AngularJS, which seems to perform very poorly when alot of "elements" are added to the page. On my computer it takes about 20 seconds just to render the elements in this folder structure. (each folder contains 10 subfolders in this example with 10 items each, so in total 110 folders and 1001 elements):

[image: picture of a datastore with many elements]

I already read alot of angularjs performance and so on yet couldnt find an appropriate answer. I already profiled the thing:

[image: Chrome rendered performance profile]

I have uploaded the profile here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KhzIo91IVv80q3Jl6w--ivgvFh78Y-Sm/view?usp=sharing

This is a full page reload where the service worker finished reloading everything at 16s. Afterwards it takes the client about 2s to read and decrypt the datastore from the backend and then this "XHR Load of view/tree-view.html" takes him about 20s which is currently the one troubling me.

tree-view.html looks quite simple:

https://gitlab.com/psono/psono-client/blob/master/src/common/data/view/tree-view.html

Yet that one loads the treeView that loads the treeViewNodes recursive:

https://gitlab.com/psono/psono-client/blob/master/src/common/data/js/directive/treeViewNode.js

I already tried to optimize that one with onetime bindings and so on to reduce the angularjs juju required to render it and so on yet without any hope.

I currently have an user who has to wait 5 to 10 minutes to load a datastore with 2500 entries.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should create a smaller example for asking here. That's really too long to be read. 
Just as first mind, if you need to load 2500 entries, try to use multiple ajax requests instead of displaying them all together, maybe using infinite scroll technique

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ill try to create a small demo project code snippet to reproduce the problem. About the rest of your comment, the problem is about rendering everything, the 1 ajax call that I actually make is not the issue ;). "Infinite scroll technice" (it doesnt apply here, yet I get the thought) I also thought about something like just rendering the folders and so on that are expanded and leave out the collapesed ones. Yet I was hoping for an alternative solution as it would cause rendering problems when I search my datastore structure.

Comment: 5 to 10mn ? AngularJS isn't your only problem there. You're obsviously loading the whole tree structure before even the user start navigating in it. You shouldn't do that, your tree component should allow you tolazy load children somehow.

Comment: "lazyloading" is a way to go, yet I was hoping for a better solution, as lazyloading will produce problems later on when i for example search and expand all folders, and then filter the ones that dont have a match out. 2500 elements still does not sound a much for a modern computer, thats why I cannot believe so far that the only solution is to reduce the number of elements.

Comment: 43 MB of data, that's some stuff to render ...

Comment: All of the above comments seem accurate to me. Your question title presumes that the problem is with AngularJS, and if so then I expect you need to do something to tamp Angular's change detection. But honestly, the problem might not be AngularJS. Have you tried displaying your data in a greatly simplified version of your web page using only vanilla Javascript? That would tell you if AngularJS really was the culprit.

Comment: @David 43 MB? The raw json encoded data that is rendered should be a couple of KB...

Comment: @JordanWilcken I didnt yet find the time for a smaller demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem, so I leave here the solution for everyone who is investigating a similar problem.

The solution was actually quite simple:

I was using ng-show instead of ng-if in the directives template in this line here:

```
'<div class="tree-folder-content"'+ (collapsible ? ' ng-show="node.expanded || node.expanded_temporary"' : '') + '>' +
'<div tree-view-node="{\'data\': node}">' +
'</div>' +
'</div>' +
```

(Link to the original code: https://gitlab.com/psono/psono-client/blob/master/src/common/data/js/directive/treeViewNode.js#L520)

ng-if prevents rendering of "unnecessary" elements, reducing the necessary amount of DOM elements dramatically.